# Intel HD driver version 10.18.10.4276 vs 15.33.38.64.4252?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, intel-graphics

I am having Intel HD driver version 10.18.10.4276 (for Intel® HD Graphics 2500):

[image]

The Intel Driver Update Utility suggests a new driver 15.33.38.64.4252:
[image]

but when I install it, it says that this version is older than the current one (10.18.10.4276):

[image]

Should I proceed with the installation? Is this just a false positive?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Intel link](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD%20Graphics%202500), the driver `10.18.10.4252` seams to be a specific Windows 10 driver, while the `10.18.10.4276` applies to 7, 8.1 and also 10. The Intel tool seams to have a bug, so stay at the `10.18.10.4276` and you're fine.