# Intel offers me two different HD Graphics drivers: Which should I choose?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics

For clarity, the question following is the reverse of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1012375/intel-hd-driver-version-10-18-10-4276-vs-15-33-38-64-4252).

I have installed in my machine (Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview (10.0.10240) the Intel HD Graphics 4000 Driver in version **15.33.38.64.4252 (10.18.10.4252)** (so called *Intel® Graphics Driver for Windows® 10 [15.33]*), but when i use Intel's Driver Update Utility it offer me other version alongside the one already installed on my system: **15.33.42.4358 (10.18.10.4358)**, called *Intel® Graphics Driver for Windows® 7*, 8.1*,10 [15.33]*.

Both are listed under [this search](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD%20Graphics%204000), and my question is: What the difference between both drivers? And which should i choose? Staying with current driver (W10 specific!?) or change to W7/8/10 version?

Is good to mention when i started Spore after downloaded from Origin it says me my drivers are outdated, that's why i search for drivers updates in first place.

Comment: Notice that they are different versions.

Comment: How are you on the stable build but in the Insider Preview?  You need to install Version 1511, if you want help, your not running the current build of Windows 10

Comment: Whoa! I have an original copy of Windows and i get the ISO from media creation tool, AFTER they release W10... Very strange Microsoft pushed the wrong version for me.